# Macbook Pro 15" bad hissing sounds when connecting external monitor and external speakers

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, display

i'm using a Macbook pro 15" i5 and I'm hearing bad statics sounds when connecting my external speaker while connecting an external monitor through the vga displayport.

The static sounds that come out through the speaker changes depending on the brightness of the external display. When the external display displays a dark output, the static pitch is high; when the external monitor diplays a bright output, the static coming through the speakers is low pitched.

If I don't plug the external monitor, just the external speaker, there is no static sound.

Please help me.

Comment: Try plugging in the wall-charger using the full cable (the one with 3 prongs, not the stubby little two-prongue connector that snaps into the brick) and see if that doesn't quiet things down.

Answer (score 1):

What you're hearing is just [electrical noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_noise) interference. The reason it depends on what's on the display is probably because it takes the display more power to show white than black.

To fix/help this problem:

- Make sure that everything is plugged in all the way to its proper connector.
- Make sure that you're using high- or
  medium-quality cables, connectors,
  and other components.
- Use an external sound card like [this one](https://store.griffintechnology.com/imic) or USB speakers [like these](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/speakers-audio/home-pc-speakers/devices/199).

Comment: An external amplifier, connected trough optical cable  (mini-toslink) would be an option too.

Comment: Note that you don't need a “high quality” as in “expensive” cable; you just need a *shielded* cable to block out the electrical noise. There are a lot of extremely overpriced cables on the market, especially for analog audio.

Comment: Also, arrange your cables so that the audio cable is as far away from the video cable as possible.

Comment: Also, use speakers designed for use with a computer, they have shielded cabinets/enclosures. Un-shielded speakers can pick up digital noise from your mouse as well as your monitor.